# Integrating real maps in optaplanner

Tags: optaplanner

I'm trying to implement optaplanner in a real logistics company but I'm having some trouble tweaking it. I would like to be able to use real maps and set customer locations onto these real maps. Right now I'm just using the XML file of the example with 32 customers and replacing those lat and long values with real lats and longs of real locations, but that is definitely not the way to go.

I'm not really getting anything form the documentation of optaplanner either. Those anybody know a way to implement real maps into the optaplanner vehicle routing problem?

Comment: What's your understanding of "real maps"? Because I'm pretty sure someone has integrated it with Google Maps already. https://google.com/search?q=optaplanner+google+maps

Comment: You can probably find most of what you want in this blog post: http://www.optaplanner.org/blog/2015/03/10/VisualizingVehicleRoutingWithLeafletAndGoogleMaps.html

Comment: Thanks you guys, I really appreciate this. But this is part of the documentation that didn't really make sense to me. I guess I was expecting optaplanner to have a full step by step guide. I'm just out of my league here. ut thank you very much for the response anywayB